# Vuejs - How can I fix the position of the eye icon in the password field?

Tags: css, vue.js, input-field

I put an eye icon at the right end of my password input fields. However, some of my error messages may appear on the page from time to time to indicate problems with my input fields. Since these error messages appear under the relevant input field, the position of the eye icon that I placed in the password field changes. Here is my password field with an eye icon. (To see the password in text format, the user needs to click and hold.)

```
      <div>
        <label></label>
        <input :type="show ? 'text' : 'password'" id="password" v-model="password"/>
        <div class="eyeButton">
          <span @mousedown="show = !show" @mouseup="show = !show" @touchstart="show = !show" @touchend="show = !show" style="cursor: pointer;">eye_icon</span>
        </div>
        <small class="errorMessage" v-if="password.error">Password field is required.</small>    
      </div>
```

Ignore the line with the error message. I simplified it a bit compared to the original code because it doesn't matter in the question. I just left it for you to see there is a conditional error message there.

And there is some additional CSS to put the eye icon inside the password input field.

```
.eyeButton {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 4px;
  top: 23px;
}
```

And here is my question with an obvious screenshot.

The eye icon should look like this even if the error message appears below the input field.

[image]

But when the error message is added to the page, naturally the position of the eye icon also changes. I need to get rid of that. Here is how it looks;

[image]

How can I adjust the position of the eye icon to cooperate with the input field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your input and icon into a div with relative position like so:

```html
<div style="position: relative">
  <input :type="show ? 'text' : 'password'" id="password" v-model="password"/>
  <div class="eyeButton">
    <span @mousedown="show = !show" @mouseup="show = !show" @touchstart="show = !show" @touchend="show = !show" style="cursor: pointer;">eye_icon</span>
  </div>
</div>
<small class="errorMessage" v-if="password.error">Password field is required.</small>
```

Of course I would suggest to use some utility classes from your CSS framework or create a custom CSS class. From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), you can read that an absolute element is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor.

Otherwise you could also remove `bottom: 4px;` from `.eyeButton`.

Comment: <div class="relative w-full flex"> I tried this one and also giving inline CSS to div to be relative but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you remove the `small` tag from the div you created?